# Row of images that has the same left margin as other content

Tags: html, css, flexbox, overflow, margin

My goal is to add a row of images that has the same `margin-left` as the other content on the page, like the title in the image below. The row of images should scroll horizontally and be visible to the end of each side of the page. The content on has `max-width: 90rem` and `margin: 0 auto`

How would you solve this?

[image: Horizontal scroll and correct margin]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I get, you want to 'break' the centering of the carousel div with images, and want to have a full width container inside a wrapper container.

This should do the trick:

```css
.alignfull {
    margin-right: calc( 50% - 50vw );
    margin-left: calc( 50% - 50vw );
    width: 100vw;
    max-width: 100vw;
}
```

This centers your div insides it, and gives it -50% margin on both sides in order to match the screen size width.

Source: one of the Twenty themes of WordPress.

Comment: Thanks for the `margin-left: calc( 50% - 50vw )`. That solved the it.
I used it like this: `div::before { content: ""; margin-left: calc( 50% - 45vw );}`